# Getting Key "Error: __getitem__ = lambda x, i: x._get_current_object()[i] KeyError: 'token_expires'"

Tags: python, lambda, flask

I am getting a `KeyError` in my flask code. In the following function `authenticated_resource` is used for token based authentication. Here I am checking the token expiration time with the current time to see if expire time is greater than current time, and then it will forward to resources, otherwise to the login page.

The `KeyError` is at `expires=datetime.strptime(...)`

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 368, in <lambda>
    __getitem__ = lambda x, i: x._get_current_object()[i]
KeyError: 'token_expires'
```

I searched for answers anbd it was mentioned that this error occurs if the key doesn't exist. So I added two line of code before `expires=datetime.strptime`

```
print 'Key exists or not=',flask_session.get("authenticated")
print 'expire =', datetime.strptime(flask_session['token_expires'],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

Which gives following result

```
Key exits or not= True  
expire = 2015-09-07 15:17:2**2
```

So the key *does* exist. Why is this happening?

```
from flask import session as flask_session, abort
from functools import wraps
from datetime import datetime
def authenticated_resource(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        now= datetime.utcnow().replace(microsecond=0)
        print 'flask_session["token_expires"]=', flask_session['token_expires']
        expires=datetime.strptime(flask_session['token_expires'],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

        print 'expires=', expires
        #expires= '2015-09-07 13:51:10'
        #print 'now=', now
        if expires <= now:  # If token is already expires 
          #print 'yes'
          flask_session.pop("auth_token", None) # Destroying the token
          flask_session.pop("authenticated", None)
          return redirect(url_for('login'))
        if flask_session.get("authenticated"):  # if token is not expires
          return function(*args, **kwargs)
        return redirect(url_for('login')) # unauthenticated
    return decorated
```

Comment: This just means you don't have a key `token_expires` in your `flask_session`.

Comment: @MattHealy   thanks for reply. I printed the value it is giving value please check it `flask_session["token_expires"]= 2015-09-07T15:01:35Z
expires= 2015-09-07 15:01:35
`